# Prevent switching to another application VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms

This may not be possible, but I am looking for a way to prevent the user from switching away from my application until it is closed.

I am using `AppActivate` and `SendKeys` to send data to the last window opened before my application was started (I'm using `GetTopWindow`, `GetNextWindow`, `IsWindowVisible`, and `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to get the PID of the last active window). However this seems to be unreliable based on when I get the PID of the last window in my application and whether the user starts switching to different windows while my application is running which can cause the wrong window to pop up.

Comment: Look into [**Desktops**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681928(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: Possibly consider doing automation with something less fragile than the "who has input focus game".  Look at: [System.Windows.Automation Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation(v=vs.110).aspx) and don't be put off by it stating that its for WPF.  It can be used in Winforms get fine.